# Publishing the results of CCCC and XUnit test plugins through jenkinsfile in a Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a freestyle ROS job on jenkins that I recently converted to a pipeline job. I want to publish test reports, code coverage report and the like for the said job in the last stage after having generated the relevant reports in an earlier stage. All the other post build actions were easy to implement except for publishing CCCC report and XUnit test coverage report. I suspect some plugins like these two are not compatible with jenkins pipeline (Jenkinsfile). Is there a workaround for me to get these two post-build actions published for my job from the Jenkinsfile? Basic, but I am stuck.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283203/publishing-the-results-of-cccc-and-xunit-test-plugins-through-jenkinsfile-in-a-pipeline/) by [HalfBloodPrince7](https://answers.ros.org/users/33775/halfbloodprince7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since this question doesn't apply exclusively to ROS builds. I think you'll have more luck asking on the [Jenkins users mailing lists](https://jenkins.io/mailing-lists/). My understanding is that plugins must add support for pipeline projects so not all plugins have done so. There is a list of [Plugins that support pipeline](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) maintained in the pipeline plugin repository.

The xUnit plugin is listed as working with pipeline from 1.100 on and the wiki page includes a pipeline example: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin#xUnitPlugin-WorkingwithPipelines

CCCC [is listed as abandoned](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/CCCC+Plugin) and hasn't been updated since 2011 so it is unlikely to ever receive pipeline support.

---

Originally posted by [nuclearsandwich](https://answers.ros.org/users/30752/nuclearsandwich/) with karma: 906 on 2018-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [HalfBloodPrince7](https://answers.ros.org/users/33775/halfbloodprince7/) on 2018-02-23**:
xUnit plugin worked just fine. Thank you for the link. Yes, CCCC doesn't seem to have any support right now. I'll just work with a downstream job for publishing all my test reports.